# Why does it show "Open with Code" on context menu on desktop?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

After Installing [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) Why does it show "Open with Code" on context menu on desktop?

Why does VS Code considers windows desktop as something which can be edited with VS Code?

Comment: Do you also have "Open with Code" in folders' right-click menus?

Comment: yes I have......ignore dots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desktop is a folder. It's located in `C:\Users\<YourUsername>\Desktop` (adjust drive letter and localized folder names to your system).

VS Code workspaces are based on folders. You can use *File → Open Folder* in Code's menu to open a workspace for some folder. Alternatively, you can right-click a folder in Windows Explorer and click *Open with Code*. You can also open a folder and right-click empty space to open the same context menu.

Right-clicking empty space on the desktop works like right-clicking empty space in the Desktop folder. Thus, an *Open with Code* item which opens desktop as a workspace.